# how to pass a variable from href to flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

this is my flask python code:

```
@app.route('/ques/<string:idd>',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ques(idd):
    print idd
```

Javascript code:

```
var counts = {{ test|tojson }};
var text = "";
var texts= "";
for (i = 1; i < counts.length; i=i+2){
    texts=counts[i-1];
    document.write("<a href=\"{{url_for('ques',idd=texts)}}\">"+counts[i]+"</a></br></br>");
}
```

how to pass idd to python function?

Comment: It's a JavaScript code...

Comment: yeah it is! how do i pass idd to python function? @Yuval Pruss

Comment: perform a get request to the route?

Comment: The get request wouldn't be in python, it'd be your javascript

Comment: is my code right ? @keef Baker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jinja gets **rendered on the server** so you can't mix and match it with javascript. Try something like this:

```
var counts = {{ test|tojson }},
    // before the HTML file gets to the browser this line will be:
    // baseURL = "/ques/REPLACE"
    baseURL = "{{ url_for('ques', idd='REPLACE') }}";

for (i = 1; i < counts.length; i = i+2) {
    var url = baseURL.replace('REPLACE', counts[i-1]);
    document.write("<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + 
                   counts[i] + "</a></br></br>");
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to build the URL directly in Javascript.

**A better way of doing it would be to use request arguments:**

```
@app.route('/ques/')
def ques():
    # url is: /ques/?idd=ABC
    idd = request.args.get('idd', default='', type=str)
    print idd
```

**Javascript:**

```
var counts = {{ test|tojson }},
    baseURL = "{{ url_for('ques') }}";

for (i = 1; i < counts.length; i = i+2) {
    var url = baseURL + '?idd=' + counts[i-1];
    document.write("<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + 
                   counts[i] + "</a></br></br>");
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! its working !!!!!

Comment: but i am getting an error as"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'idd' referenced before assignment"@PJ Santoro

Comment: did you try the request.args method? i think i accidentally had a javascript formatted comment in there instead of the python way

Comment: yeah now its working..thank u so much !